# CSS corner ribbon not rotated in iPad (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, ribbon, css-shapes, css-transforms

The following CSS3 corner ribbon works perfectly on Chrome for desktop, but if you open it on an iPad, it is not rotated.

http://jsfiddle.net/u6hqte8s/1/

```css
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -15px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon"><span>Test</span>
</div>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You arent denoting the correct `-webkit-` vendor prefix for `transform: rotate(-45deg);` as [**required by safari / OSX etc**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

```
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* <--- add this */
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; left: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); **in .ribbon span class**

follow this link to get more details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Using2Dand3DTransforms/Using2Dand3DTransforms.html